# SOAP API / SQL Error "ORA 00904 invalid Identifier"

Tags: php, sql, oracle, soap

I have the following problem:

I need to get a few columns of a oracle db table to display information on a .php page. To do this, I'm using a SOAP-API, which works flawlessly with any other table, only not with this one.

This is the Code I am using for all of these Queries:

```
$setSearchObjectsIn = new SearchObjectsInType();

    $setSearchObjectsIn->sessionId = (String) $sessionId;   
    $setSearchObjectsIn->table = (String) 'STFCFG_DD_VALUE';    
    $setSearchObjectsIn->caseSensitive = (String) 'false';  
    $setSearchObjectsIn->limitedResult = (String) 'false';  
    $setSearchObjectsIn->restrictions[0]['attributeName']= (String) 'STFCFG_DD_VALUE.DDID';
    $setSearchObjectsIn->restrictions[0]['restriction']['operator'] = (String) '=';
    $setSearchObjectsIn->restrictions[0]['restriction']['value'] = (String) $ddid;

    $setSearchObjectsIn->resultColumns[0] = (String) 'STFCFG_DD_VALUE.DD_VALUE';
    $setSearchObjectsIn->resultColumns[1] = (String) 'STFCFG_DD_VALUE.CATALOG_NAME';
    $setSearchObjectsIn->resultColumns[2] = (String) 'STFCFG_DD_VALUE.MSG_ID';      

    $client = new SoapClient((String) $instance.'/axis/services/GenericApiWS?wsdl');    
    $result = $client->searchObjects($setSearchObjectsIn);
```

And this is the Error I get with this special table:

```
ORA-00904: "MAN_ID": ungültiger Bezeichner
```

I have also tried starting this query with SoapUI, which results in the exactly same thing.
The fact, that I have nothing like "MAN_ID" in my code has me wondering, as the error looks like I would query a column named like that, which I obviously don't do. (There is also no column "MAN_ID" in the requested table, so I have no idea where this comes from)

I hope you can help me

Comment: Maybe you have a trigger works with that field

Comment: ... or some other stored *procedure* or *function*.

Comment: Thank you. I have searched for different settings in this table using SQLDeveloper, but it seems like there are absolutely no differences. No triggers or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try looking for MAN_ID in the SOAP **server** code - the error may be what the server returns and it may be looking for that column implicitly. The error message is definitely produced by Oracle, so search the way your query gets there and if possible, see what query gets executed.

Comment: Thank You, I have checked the error logs and asked a colleague about it.  Due to the log messages, he told me that the API itself searches for the column MAN_ID for authentication things. A Hotfix is gonna be applied to skip that step on tables that don't have this column.